# Finding x from measure of arcs

Tags: geometry

> Solve for x. Assume that lines which appear to be diameters are actual diameters.

[image]

Not sure how to solve it. I tried adding $x+93$ to the other minor arc and setting equal to 180 but had no way of solving for x.

I also tried $360 - (x+93)$ to get the measure of the major arc but still could not see how to solve for x.

Comment: What is $x$? What do the red circle-sectors represent?

Comment: Its not clear what is $x$? Is it the angle?

Comment: $x$ is part of the arc length. The red circle-sectors' angles measure the same as the arcs they form.

Comment: @badjr In any case, I don't think there is a  unique solution.

Comment: The solution is listed as $x = -3$, but I didn't know how to arrive at that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If my interpretation of your problem is correct, then the supplied answer is invalid.

I made the following 2 assumptions:-

1. The circle is an unit circle.
2. The center angle of that sector is of 90 degrees.

Then, (x + 93) : 2π(1) = 90 : 360

x + 93 = π/2

From the last equation, the only way to get x = - 3 is

(1) the unit of x + 93 is in degrees;

(2) to interpret π as π(radian) which is 180 degrees.

However, obviously (1) is not true unless the arc length (for some unit of measure) is NUMERICALLY equal to the size of the angle subtended at center (which is x + 93 degrees).

Also, the assumption like (2) is also incorrect because the π in this case has no unit at all and this π is just 3.14159….